# Azure app service auth not allowing personal accounts

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a web app deployed on azure app service. I have enabled google and Microsoft logins for the app using the app service built in authentication.

I have an app registration with this option:
Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)

Now I have associated the app service authentication with the app registration by entering the client id and secret.

I have a login button with href="https://app.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad"

Organizational accounts (non personal accounts) from other tenants and my tenant are able to use this login. Even personal accounts in my tenant (guests) are able to use this login.

But when I try with personal accounts those are not a part of my tenant the login fails with the error AADSTS50020 : User account 'example@outlook.com'/'example@gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'My Org' and cannot access the application in that tenant.

I want personal account users and business email users to use the same Microsoft login option.

Comment: What is the value configured for `authority` (it starts with `https://login.microsoftonline.com`)?

Comment: Try to change the `/tenant id` to `/common`.

Comment: Sounds like it could be using /common, but the v1 endpoint which doesn't allow MS accounts unless they are guests. You need to use the v2.0 common endpoint for that.

Comment: Since its app service built in authentication I have no where configured the urls like https://login.microsoftonline.com.. I dont know where to put /common , previously when I used MSAL there was option to configure the urls to restrict type of accounts but where to do that when using app service auth? I initiate the login from the code by directing the user to "https://app.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad"

Comment: @juunas How do I configure v2 endpoint for app service authentication? Should I add issuer URL in advanced management configuration?

Comment: Is this the login url?  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Comment: @CarlZhao yes changing /tenant to common worked!

Comment: So, is your problem solved?

Comment: This particular problem is solved but gave rise to a new one; by adding  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0 to issuer url now causes logout to give CORS error in the console. When i make get request to '/.auth/logout' it doesn't logout it shows Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common... " has been blocked by CORS. This issue occurs only for aad. For google login configured on app service authentication logout and login is seamless.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by changing the issuer url in advanced setting of AAD configuration in app service authentication. I set it to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0.
But now the logout gives cors issue. This occurs only for microsoft account. For Google login through the app service auth logout works fine.